# Enum with QList and Pointers

Tags: qt, pointers, enums, qt5, qlist

I'm currently trying to convert my `QList<QString*>` to an enum version so it can be faster.

I would like to do the following, `QList<EnumType*>`. I am wondering if there is any reason I shouldn't do this. I could really benefit from the pointer in the `QList` for my next step which is to convert it to a `QQmlListProperty<EnumType>` which takes a `QList<EnumType*>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in managing enum values or QStrings via pointer. Just use `QStringList` (which is a `QList<QString>`) or `QList<SomeEnum>`. QQmlListProperty is for managing QObjects, as the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qqmllistproperty.html#details) says:

> Note: QQmlListProperty can only be used for lists of QObject-derived object pointers.

Neither QStrings nor enums are. What the best solution is to expose the list to QML depends on your use case.